# What is the equivalent of `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` from pandas in polars?

Tags: python, duplicates, unique, python-polars

What is the equivalent of `drop_duplicates()` from pandas in polars?

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,2], "b":[2,2,3], "c":[1,2,3]})
df
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(["a", "b"])
```

Delivers the following error:

AttributeError: drop_duplicates not found

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The right function name is `.unique()`

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,2], "b":[2,2,3], "c":[1,2,3]})
df.unique(subset=["a","b"])
```

And this delivers the right output:

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: `df.distinct()` can be ran without any parameters. Appears it was only included to answer this questions. Polars has very good docstrings, run `help(df.distinct)` or `help(df.[method])` to find examples and default parameters. More info [Polars Cookbook](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/introduction.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's renamed to .unique()

See their [Polars Documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unique.html#polars-dataframe-unique)